# Why do these two char arrays return different results?

Tags: c

I just assigned an ip to a char array and printed it to make sure it was right and got the following results:

```
int
main(void)
{
    char ip [11] = "65.55.57.27";
    printf(ip);
    return 0;
}
```

I get

```
65.55.57.270 "
```

But if I increase the array size to 12

```
int
main(void)
{
    char ip [12] = "65.55.57.27";
    printf(ip);
    return 0;
}
```

I get

```
65.55.57.27
```

Can anyone explain this? Why is it that the array of size 11 return a 13 char result while the array of size 12 returns a 11 char result?

Comment: Please decide which language you're actually interested in. This is *not* C#.

Answer (score 5):

The array in

```
char ip [11] = "65.55.57.27";
```

has no space for the [NUL terminator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string) since the string literal is exactly 11 characters long.

This results in

```
printf(ip);
```

having [undefined behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Either of the following would fix the problem:

```
char ip [12] = "65.55.57.27";
char ip [] = "65.55.57.27";
```

Comment: Just to add to this answer. Run in any good C IDE this 11 length gives out a descriptive error as well `initializer-string for array of chars is too long`

Comment: @HankyPankyㇱ: Actually, in this particular case I wouldn't expect to get a warning (of course if `ip` was declared as `char ip[10]`, that would be a different kettle of fish altogether).

Comment: @NPE why not? The string **is** 12 chars long.

Comment: That's true but when I ran OP's code I saw that warning so I thought I'll add it here to complement your answer

Comment: @Aneri: I think it's reasonable for the compiler to think that, if I went through the trouble of explicitly specifying the size of the array, and it happens to match exactly the length of the string literal, that I simply *don't want* the NUL. This is certainly how `gcc` behaves, and I think it's spot-on.

Answer (score 1):

You made space for 11 bytes but there also exists the implicit null byte `\0` in your char array:

```
>> ip

   {'6', '5', '.', '5', '5', '.', '5', '7', '.', '2', '7', '\0'}
```

Hence your array has 12 elements in it, 1 too many for the size. You should have gotten an error on your compiler. This is what I got:

> `error: initializer-string for char array is too long`

I don't like to deal with these trivial problems; that's why I use [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string):

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string str = "65.55.57.27";

    std::cout << str;
}
```

[***Live Demo***](http://liveworkspace.org/code/4yc7Hy%243062)